# Having trouble reaching gRPC service running securely inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

I am having an issue connecting to a gRPC app running in kubernetes from outside the node/cluster. From within the cluster, connections work without an issue, from outside of the cluster I get the following errors:

NOTE: services inside and outside the cluster are using the same gRPC client to connect.

On the server side:

```
ssl_transport_security.cc:1824] No match found for server name: <myDomain.com>
```

On the client side:

```
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1627334018.361000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5420,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1627334018.361000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

Kubernetes is set up as follows:

- A Deployment with the gRPC app running on a secure channel
- A Service running using nodePorts to bind node to pod ports. For example, the secure channel is `0.0.0.0:50051` and the service node port is configured as follows:

  > nodePort: 30001  port: 50051  targetPort: 50051
- SSL cert/key are set up as an opaque secrets, this is used by other services inside the cluster to access the gRPC app. SSL cert is created with the proper alt names, one of which is the service name of the gRPC Kubernetes Service I created. These services connect to the gRPC app without issue

If I am understanding correctly, this should route any traffic to 30001 on the node, to 50051 on the pod.

Questions:

- Since I am running a secure channel, I presume SSL termination is happening on my gRPC server. How is it possible that inside the cluster, SSL is working when other services are connecting to the service, but from outside it fails?

Comment: assuming that this is a self signed certificate did the client use a public certificate to connect to the service.

Comment: You're resolving in-cluster using the Kubernetes-internal Service DNS name which is in the service's certs alt-name *but* outside the cluster, the service will be addressed by IP or at least a different name that isn't one of the service's alt-names

Comment: I think (!) generally you'd want to SSL terminate at the Ingress. This gives you the ability to more consistently resolve certs at the perimeter and then you could mTLS inside the cluster to take advantage of Kubernetes DNS resolution and certificate management

Comment: Thanks for the discussion: 
internally we resolve with the kubernetes internal service DNS name, which is listed as an alt name. Our node is on a network with a hostname assigned as well, which is also in the alt names list. We do not use any public certificates to connect.

Comment: @DazWilkin does SSL termination at the Ingress level involve having the gRPC app expose an insecure connection?

Comment: Whenever you terminate before the "origin" (server), you potentially have an issue. However, as you're experiencing, terminating at the service can make life more... inflexible. If the Kubernetes (Ingress) terminates, you can still re-TLS the internal to Kubernetes connection. Alternatively, if you want to preserve end-to-end, you'll want to provide a more stable (and public) DNS name for the service.

Comment: @aramnhammer, is your problem now resolved?

Comment: Nope, I will get back to trying to resolve it next week probably.

Comment: @aramnhammer, any progress?

Comment: Pushed again, have some other things to work on that are more pressing at the moment.

Comment: Which version Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a botched line in the `cnf` file. Which caused my list of `alternate_names` not to be fully included in the resulting `cert` file. I discovered this by using a `cert` viewer and noticed the `alternate_names` I expected were not there.